# How do I use the mpi.h in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, parallel-processing, mpi, mpich

I have installed MPICH3.2 from the following the direction in given website

http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/installing-mpich2/

I downloaded the tar file and in Downloads/ directory and installed using terminal.I wanted to test if my program works on my local machine before I submit to the remote machine.

The problem is when I write the header #include "mpi.h" Xcode doesn't recognize it. How do I add the MPICH library to the Xcode ? or how do I make it so that Xcode compiles using mpi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I, personally, would go like this (please note I never compile MPI code in XCode - I do it via Makefile, CMake).

I would have got MPI installed in certain location (from sources) - take a look here how to do it: [Running Open MPI on macOS](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3492)

Then, I'd have created supper simple MPI code (e.g. like this)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int my_rank, p, n;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    printf("size: %d rank: %d\n", p, my_rank);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Then, I'd have it compiled using mpicc (as mentioned by @Gilles).

```
> mpicc -v -o mpi ./mpi.c
> mpirun -np 4 ./mpi
size: 4 rank: 1
size: 4 rank: 2
size: 4 rank: 0
size: 4 rank: 3
```

Option `-v` will give you all the locations you need. Then, I'd have taken all these options into XCode.

You can also use `mpicc -show` to get flags required to build MPI based code.

In fact, it should work out of the box. Take a look here:

You need to set includes (as at the picture)

[image]

and MPI lib (as in the picture)

[image]

and, you should be able to run it as well

[image]

To get it running using `mpirun`, make sure to set: `Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme`. And, make sure to change `Arguments` to

[image]

and `Executable` to `mpirun` - it should be inside `bin` directory where you have your MPI installed.

[image]

**Update**

It looks like `XCode 11.0` requires passing library location as well. In the past it was inferred from the file. Now, you have to pass it explicitly inside build settings

[image]

Once you update this location. It will work as expected.

[image]

Comment: .oOo. Cool it worked for you ;) If you find this answer helpful, please consider accepting it and marking as a solution for your question ;) .oOo.

Comment: Is the original poster still here? I am getting a '''ld: library not found for -lmpi.20''' error

Comment: @Rio1210 - it looks like in `XCode 11.0` you have to pass library location into search path explicitly. To be honest, I haven't tried that since 2017, but I can confirm that for new `XCode` it is required to set little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

the "natural" way of building a `MPI` application is to used the `MPI` wrappers (e.g. `mpicc` and friends) instead of the native compiler (e.g. `gcc` / `clang` and friends). by doing this, `mpi.h` will be in the include path, and you will not need to manually link with the various `MPI` libraries (which is MPI implementation specific by the way)